# blogger custom template - bizarre color

Tags: html, blogs

I have a blog at www.discosinauditos.com

I am using this template called cosmo. When I switched to the new editor in blogger all the post headings and hyperlinks switched from this mild white to this hideous blue color. I am no expert in html, but I have looked to it and have not been able to correct this color.

Since this template is not provided by blogger, I am not allowed to correct colors easily.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that that "bizarre" blue color is the default for an anchor tag.

Looking at the HTML source, I can see that those blue headers are `<a>` tags nested inside of `<h3>` tags which have a `class='entity-title'` which isn't defined. You can see that if you find the first occurrence of Goldmine in the HTML.

One solution would be for you to define that class in the style for the theme, which you can see near the top of the HTML source code.